# How to avoid multiple query to get child relationship count in Laravel one to many Realtionship

Tags: sql, laravel

I have 3 tables they are regional with model Regional (id,kode), status_kontrak with model StatusKontrak (id,status,user_id,...,...), an users with User Model (id, regional_id). My purpose is to get a collection or array from StatusKontrak tou count how many StatusKontrak with status of active, expired, and null of each user respectively to its regional. This is how I try to accomplish that.

```
public function buildSummaryByRegional()
{
    $regional = Regional::has('am')->with('am.regional','am.statusKontrak','am.activeStatusKontrak','am.expiredStatusKontrak','am.nullStatusKontrak')->get();
    $summaryRegional = [];
    foreach($regional as $r){
        //$r->am->loadCount('statusKontrak','activeStatusKontrak','expiredStatusKontrak','nullStatusKontrak');
        $am = $r->am;
        $in_prefix=[];
        foreach($am as $a){
            $parts = explode("@", $a->email);
            $prefix = $parts[0];
            $in_prefix[] = $prefix;   
            $a->prefix = $prefix;             
            $account = $a->statusKontrak->count();
            $active = $a->activeStatusKontrak->count();
            $expired = $a->expiredStatusKontrak->count();
            $null = $a->nullStatusKontrak->count();
            $summaryRegional[$r->kode]['am'][] = [
                'am'=>$a,
                'account'=>$account,
                'active'=>$active,
                'expired'=>$expired,
                'null'=>$null
            ];
        }
        $summaryRegional[$r->kode]['account']=StatusKontrak::whereIn('am',$in_prefix)->count();                
        $summaryRegional[$r->kode]['active'] = StatusKontrak::whereIn('am',$in_prefix)->where('status','active')->count();
        $summaryRegional[$r->kode]['expired'] = StatusKontrak::whereIn('am',$in_prefix)->where('status','expired')->count();
        $summaryRegional[$r->kode]['null'] = StatusKontrak::whereIn('am',$in_prefix)->where('status','NULL')->count();
    }
    return $summaryRegional;
}
```

it works fine but I know it's not a best practice. How to optimize this to a simpler way, of course yes to reduce n+1 problem.

Comment: If this works and you’re looking for a more optimised solution, you should post it on Code Review instead. They will be happy to provide you with some feedback.

Comment: where to post so i cant get a review?

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/